# Get attr of url inside ckeditor jQuery

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am wondering if there is a possibility to change href attr inside CKEDITOR.

I have an check box outside ckeditor with class email-checkbox, and ckeditor text box wth generated text. Inside this generated text is a href with id open-redirect, now I want to add value to href of this link. This is single link unique and is always in generated message. My code looks for now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    carrier.add();
});

var carrier = {
    add: function(){
        $(".email-checkbox").click(function(){
            var values = $('input:checkbox:checked.email-checkbox').map(function(){return this.value;}).get();
            var href = $('#open-redirect').attr('href');

            {now href is undefined and I need to add checkbox value to it}
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: You can't add a checkbox to a hyperlink's `href` attribute. The `href` attribute is used to determine where the hyperlink should point.

Comment: I mean checkbox value not tag :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `click()` instead use [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/):

```
$(".email-checkbox").change(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#open-redirect').attr('href', this.value);
    }
});
```